# VBSCRIPT in UFT in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, hp-uft

**Scenario**:  In an Excel Sheet there are URLs of 100 webpages.

1. UFT should iterate through each row, read the  cell data(URL) from the Excel Sheet
2. Navigate to each URL and
3. Print the current webaddress of each of the URL after navigation.

Using: `Browser("bname").Page("pname").GetROProperty("URL")` would require to know the "pname" of each of the navigated URLs.  This requires manual intervention and is hectic.  Is there anyother way to print the current URL of each of the navigated webpage?

Comment: `Browser` objects only ever have one `Page` object, and it is merely a method of organising the Object Repository.  So you won't need to know all the `pname` values.  I recommend you look up Descriptive Programming - otherwise you will need to have all 100 browser objects stored in the repository in order to recognise them

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

for your 1 step where you are reading the data from excel, you can use dictionary object or something to store each URL
then you can use something like -

```
a = "www.google.com" 'here you are need to parameterize each URL read from dictionary'
 For i = 1 to 100 'this can made dynamic till the count of rows'
   Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   objIE.Visible = True
   objIE.Navigate a
   wait(2) 'you can use wait/sync dynamically'
   newURL = Browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").GetROProperty("URL")
   Print newURL 'here you can change it to log it to textfile or excel'
   objIE.quit()
Next
```

this is just to brief an idea, you may chose to update/change based on your need.